# How to access results from API to display to my UI? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

I'm currently making an API call inside my App component in React Native. I'm using fetch to capture a few values and storing them in variables within my fetch. How can I access those varaiables inside my return statement to display to my UI?

This is what my component looks like right now, I need "lessonDesc" and "lessonName" values inside my return statement where you see "NEED DATA HERE"

````
export default function App() {



fetch(contentURL).then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => {
  let lessonName = json.fields.lessonName
  console.log(json.fields.lessonName);
  let lessonDesc = json.fields.lessonDesc

  console.log(json.fields.lessonDesc);
  return lessonDesc
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
})


return (
  
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{NEED DATA HERE}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way that is you use **useState** for updating variables and you can access that variables in all around in the your Component , also you are be able to define states separately or all together , in this case we defined separately. So you can try it:

```
export default function App() {
   const [lessonName, setLessonName] = React.useState("");
   const [lessonDesc, setLessonDesc] = React.useState("");

   React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(contentURL).then((response) => 
      response.json()).then((json) => {
        setLessonName(
          json.fields.lessonName
        );
        setLessonDesc(
           json.fields.lessonDesc
        );
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
   } , []);

return (
  
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{NEED DATA HERE}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```